# How to change other element classes by clicking on an element inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-class

I have an ng-repeat code in angularjs like this:

```html
<th ng-repeat="row in results.rows track by $index">
  {{row.name | translate}}
  <a class="sort" 
     ng-click="orderResultDataEvent($index)" 
     ng-if="results.tableOptions.sortable">
    <i ng-class="{'icon icon-exc-column-hover-sort': row.isReverseOrder == null,'icon icon-exc-sort-numeric-1-9': row.isReverseOrder === false , 'icon icon-exc-sort-numeric-9-1': row.isReverseOrder === true }" 
       class="text-white" 
       aria-hidden="true">
    </i>
  </a>
</th>
```

Also a result table like this:
[image]

what I'm looking is: when a user clicks on the first column for sorting, the other columns icon will be changed to the defualt icon like the first column. and icon of the first column, will be changed to sorted icon.

what happens right now is, other icons won't be changed when for example a user clicks on the first column sort icon.

Comment: Can you include your js for the ng-click function?

Comment: there is nothing in this function. it's being used for sorting 
        $scope.tableEntryClickEvent = onTableClick;
        $scope.filterResultDataEvent = onFilter;
        $scope.orderResultDataEvent = onOrderBy;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like the below code. Also you can check [this plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/PqWwRxeFMD42LgB0?preview) for your working example scenario.

**Template:**

```
<th ng-repeat="hed in results.header track by $index"  ng-click="setSelected($index)">
   {{hed.value}}
   <a class="sort">
      <span class="actual" ng-class="{'toggle': $index === selectedId }">#</span>
   </a>
</th>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.selectedId = null;
$scope.setSelected = function($index) {
   $scope.selectedId = $index;
   console.log($scope.selectedId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. it's exactly what I was looking. the only question is, I have already a function in my ng-click, is it possible to pass two different functions via ng-click?

Comment: Yes. You can do for sure. For that you need to use semicolon **;** between your functions. **e.g: ng-click="setSelected($index);someOtherFunction(param)"**

Comment: awesome, Thanks a lot.

Comment: I Appreciate if you Up-Vote the answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: I did but it seems because I'm totally new here, it doesn't effect before I reach to some steps. anyway based on what you explained, I changed my html code to the following and used your js file and it successfully worked: <i ng-class="$index != selectedColumnId ? 'icon icon-exc-column-hover-sort' : row.isReverseOrder === false ? 'icon icon-exc-sort-numeric-9-1' : 'icon icon-exc-sort-numeric-1-9'" class="text-white" aria-hidden="true"></i>